# Component not rendering in React Router multi step form

Tags: reactjs, react-router

so im using react router and formik to create a multi step form. ive based my booking application on this article.

https://codedaily.io/tutorials/50/Create-a-Form-Wizard-with-Data-Loss-Prevention-using-Formik-and-React-Router

ive got the basic routing down. Im just trying to redirect the user to Section 1 of my booking form when they land on the /make-a-booking url. its pretty simple but im not sure if im missing something. So the issue im having is that the ContactSection isnt rendering anything. Is it possible to create a multi step form with just formik?

Here is the link to the githib repo.
https://github.com/umxr/booking-form

Here is the code for the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormWizard from './components/FormWizard';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Home from './components/Home';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/make-a-booking" component={FormWizard} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code for the FormWizard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import ContactSection from './sections/ContactSection';
import PhoneSection from './sections/PhoneSection';

class FormWizard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <Redirect from="/make-a-booking" to="/make-a-booking/contact" />
                    <Route exact path="/make-a-booking/contact" component={ContactSection} />
                    <Route exact path="/make-a-booking/phone" component={PhoneSection} />
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}

export default FormWizard;
```

the contactSection and PhoneSection currently just render out a string along the lines of 'this is the phone section' etc

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work ? We can't guess what's wrong .

Comment: @sagi the contactSection doesnt render anything. the form gets redirected fine but nothing gets rendered to the view